# Are there any fast ways to compile and run/show .tex file using gedit?

Tags: gedit, latex

So after 16.10 texmaker has been rather reluctant to cooperate with me and I'm forced to use gedit, not that I mind, I use gedit for everything else, but I miss some of texmakers features, in particular the "f1" compile and run. I'm looking for something along the lines: pdflatex *tex | evince pdf*. You can tell from the previous code example that I'm not very fluent with linux:). Also I did some search around and found this french guy making a [script](https://youtu.be/QtJdLaP6ddg?t=356) to get it to work, which is basically what I need, but I couldn't get it to work after copying the text (ofc after translation). Any help would be more than welcome!

Edit: a sort-of-fix is ofcourse to make an `alias x=pdflatex *.tex;evince *.pdf &`, which will compile and display any file in you current directory ending with `.tex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a gedit plugin `gedit-latex-plugin`

```
sudo apt-get install gedit-latex-plugin
```

Use the external tool plugin to create access to envice.

- To install the plugin, go to Edit -> Preferences -> Plugins -> External Tools.
- To configure the plugin, go to Tools -> Manage External Tools.... A dialog will appear and you can start adding tools.
- To run tools, go to Tools -> External Tools or use (if applicable) associated shortcut keys.

The dialog then looks like this:
[image: External Tools Manager]

Then you can start evince directly or write a shell script for all steps together and execute.

Comment: I can't enable the plugin in gedit in *Edit* -> *Preferences* -> *Plugins* tab. When I try to enable it, it shows a red circle with a white horizontal line in the middle next to the plugin. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @karel Ensure that you have rubber installed. It is used for automated document compiling.

Comment: Now this is all well, but what is the default button for compiling and running evince? It doesn't say in the meny after installing it.

Comment: @aggsol Would you be kind and provide me details on how to setup key bindings for the quick build? http://askubuntu.com/questions/880868/how-do-i-quick-build-using-the-gedit-latex-plugin describes the current problem after installing the package you provided. Thanks

Comment: @Thomas see my edits.

Comment: @aggsol Sorry for late respond!  When I use the Build (CTRL F8) the only output I'm getting is : Running tool: build  No Makefile found! Done. Why is this? I have a .tex file in the current directory.